# How to select content type from HTTP Accept header in PHP

Tags: php, http-headers

I'm trying to build a standard compliant website framework which serves XHTML 1.1 as application/xhtml+xml or HTML 4.01 as text/html depending on the browser support. Currently it just looks for "application/xhtml+xml" anywhere in the accept header, and uses that if it exists, but that's not flexible - text/html might have a higher score. Also, it will become more complex when other formats (WAP, SVG, XForms etc.) are added. So, does anyone know of a tried and tested piece of PHP code to select, from a string array given by the server, either the one best supported by the client or an ordered list based on the client score?

Comment: While it's all good to try and be standards compliant and "do things right", I think it's worth spending a moment considering if you will actually gain any benefits from all this. E.g. not much of a reason to supply application/xhtml+xml when text/html works just fine and so on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can leverage [apache's mod_negotiation module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html). This way you can use the full range of negotiation capabilities the module offers, including *your own preferences* for the content type (e,g, "I really want to deliver application/xhtml+xml, unless the client very much prefers something else").
basic solution:

- create a .htaccess file with

  ```
  AddHandler type-map .var
  ```

  as contents
- create a file foo.var with

  ```
  URI: foo

  URI: foo.php/html
  Content-type: text/html; qs=0.7

  URI: foo.php/xhtml
  Content-type: application/xhtml+xml; qs=0.8
  ```

  as contents
- create a file foo.php with

  ```
  <?php
  echo 'selected type: ', substr($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], 1);
  ```

  as contents.
- request http://localhost/whatever/foo.var

For this to work you need mod_negotiation enabled, the appropriate AllowOverride privileges for AddHandler and [AcceptPathInfo](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo) not being disabled for $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'].
With my Firefox sending "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" and the example .var map the result is "selected type: xhtml".
You can use other "tweaks" to get rid of PATH_INFO or the need to request foo*.var*, but the basic concept is: let mod_negotiation redirect the request to your php script in a way that the script can "read" the selected content-type.

> So, does anyone know of a tried and tested piece of PHP code to select

It's not a pure php solution but I'd say mod_negotiation has been tried and tested ;-)

Answer (score 20):

Little snippet from my library:

```
function getBestSupportedMimeType($mimeTypes = null) {
    // Values will be stored in this array
    $AcceptTypes = Array ();

    // Accept header is case insensitive, and whitespace isn’t important
    $accept = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']));
    // divide it into parts in the place of a ","
    $accept = explode(',', $accept);
    foreach ($accept as $a) {
        // the default quality is 1.
        $q = 1;
        // check if there is a different quality
        if (strpos($a, ';q=')) {
            // divide "mime/type;q=X" into two parts: "mime/type" i "X"
            list($a, $q) = explode(';q=', $a);
        }
        // mime-type $a is accepted with the quality $q
        // WARNING: $q == 0 means, that mime-type isn’t supported!
        $AcceptTypes[$a] = $q;
    }
    arsort($AcceptTypes);

    // if no parameter was passed, just return parsed data
    if (!$mimeTypes) return $AcceptTypes;

    $mimeTypes = array_map('strtolower', (array)$mimeTypes);

    // let’s check our supported types:
    foreach ($AcceptTypes as $mime => $q) {
       if ($q && in_array($mime, $mimeTypes)) return $mime;
    }
    // no mime-type found
    return null;
}
```

example usage:

```
$mime = getBestSupportedMimeType(Array ('application/xhtml+xml', 'text/html'));
```

Comment: just a teeny improvement: change the function prototype to `function getBestSupportedMimeType($mimeTypes = null, $acceptedTypes = FALSE){ if ($acceptedTypes === FALSE){ $acceptedTypes = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']; } ... `. essentially allow custom accept types if the program needs to do something a little more custom.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work with "*/*" or "application/*" which are also valid entries (https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html )

Answer (score 10):

Pear::HTTP 1.4.1 has a method [string negotiateMimeType( array $supported, string $default)](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP/docs/1.4.1/HTTP/HTTP.html#methodnegotiateMimeType)

```
<?php
require 'HTTP.php';

foreach(
  array(
    'text/*;q=0.3, text/html;q=0.7, text/html;level=1, text/html;level=2;q=0.4, */*;q=0.5',
    'text/*;q=0.3, text/html;q=0.8, application/xhtml+xml;q=0.7, */*;q=0.2',
    'text/*;q=0.3, text/html;q=0.7, */*;q=0.8',
    'text/*, application/xhtml+xml',
    'text/html, application/xhtml+xml'
  ) as $testheader) {  
  $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'] = $testheader;

  $http = new HTTP;
  echo $testheader, ' -> ',
    $http->negotiateMimeType( array('application/xhtml+xml', 'text/html'), 'application/xhtml+xml'),
    "\n";
}
```

prints

```
text/*;q=0.3, text/html;q=0.7, text/html;level=1, text/html;level=2;q=0.4, /;q=0.5 -> application/xhtml+xml
text/*;q=0.3, text/html;q=0.8, application/xhtml+xml;q=0.7, */*;q=0.2 -> text/html
text/*;q=0.3, text/html;q=0.7, */*;q=0.8 -> application/xhtml+xml
text/*, application/xhtml+xml -> application/xhtml+xml
text/html, application/xhtml+xml -> text/html
```

edit: this might not be so good after all...
My firefox sends *Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8*
text/html and application/xhtml+xml have q=1.0 but PEAR::HTTP (afaik) doesn't let *you* chose which one you prefer, it returns text/html no matter what you pass as $supported. This may or may not be sufficient for you. see my other answer(s).

Comment: Note that currently `level=` was dropped. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14527918/128761 or https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2854.txt

Answer (score 9):

Just for the record, [Negotiation](http://williamdurand.fr/Negotiation/) is a pure PHP implementation for dealing with content negotiation.

Answer (score 1):

Merged @maciej-Łebkowski and @chacham15 solutions with my issues fixes and improvements. If you pass `$desiredTypes = 'text/*'` and `Accept` contains `text/html;q=1` then `text/html` will be returned.

```php
/**
 * Parse, sort and select best Content-type, supported by a user browser.
 *
 * @param string|string[] $desiredTypes The filter of desired types. If &null then the all supported types will returned.
 * @param string $acceptRules Supported types in the HTTP Accept header format. $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'] by default.
 * @return string|string[]|null Matched by $desiredTypes type or all accepted types.
 * @link Inspired by http://stackoverflow.com/a/1087498/3155344
 */
function resolveContentNegotiation($desiredTypes = null, $acceptRules = null)
{
    if (!$acceptRules) {
        $acceptRules = @$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'];
    }
    // Accept header is case insensitive, and whitespace isn't important.
    $acceptRules = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $acceptRules));

    $sortedAcceptTypes = array();
    foreach (explode(',', $acceptRules) as $acceptRule) {
        $q = 1; // the default accept quality (rating).
        // Check if there is a different quality.
        if (strpos($acceptRule, ';q=') !== false) {
            // Divide "type;q=X" into two parts: "type" and "X"
            list($acceptRule, $q) = explode(';q=', $acceptRule, 2);
        }
        $sortedAcceptTypes[$acceptRule] = $q;
    }
    // WARNING: zero quality is means, that type isn't supported! Thus remove them.
    $sortedAcceptTypes = array_filter($sortedAcceptTypes);
    arsort($sortedAcceptTypes, SORT_NUMERIC);

    // If no parameter was passed, just return parsed data.
    if (!$desiredTypes) {
        return $sortedAcceptTypes;
    }

    $desiredTypes = array_map('strtolower', (array) $desiredTypes);

    // Let's check our supported types.
    foreach (array_keys($sortedAcceptTypes) as $type) {
        foreach ($desiredTypes as $desired) {
            if (fnmatch($desired, $type)) {
                return $type;
            }
        }
    }

    // No matched type.
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You must not filter out q=0 from client Accept headers. It means the client will not accept that type, e.g. `Accept-Language: en, en-US;q=0` means I'll accept any English as long as it's not American.

Answer (score 1):

[PEAR's HTTP2 library](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP2) supports parsing all types of `Accept` headers. It's installable via [composer](https://packagist.org/packages/pear/http2) and PEAR.

Examples can be found at the [documentation](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http2.negotiatelanguage.php) or [my blog post](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/php-http-negotiation.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Client may accept a list of mime-types in the response. In the other hand the order of the response is very important for client side. [PHP Pear HTTP2](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP2/docs/1.1.2/HTTP2/HTTP2.html) is the best to deal with language, charset, and mimetypes.

```
$http = new HTTP2();
$supportedTypes = array(
    'text/html',
    'application/json'
);

$type = $http->negotiateMimeType($supportedTypes, false);
if ($type === false) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable');
    echo "You don't want any of the content types I have to offer\n";
} else {
    echo 'I\'d give you data of type: ' . $type . "\n";
}
```

Here is a good tutorial: https://cweiske.de/tagebuch/php-http-negotiation.htm