# How can I show different content to website visitors from a specific country in PHP?

Tags: php, blogs, selection

On my Wordpress blog, I want to show additional content to people from Finland on all pages. Very much like the Feedback button at the left edge of the screen on [printfriendly.com](http://www.printfriendly.com/). How can I achieve this most reliably using PHP?

Comment: You can get their lat & long with FF3.5's now geolocation! https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_geolocation
Free and easy to use... but no country information AFAIK, and not widely supported. I'm just excited for the future of web browsers :p

Comment: Are you more concerned that they are from Finland or that Finnish is the default language on their browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use the PHP GeoIP functions to determine the users location based on IP, and serve appropriate content based on that.

More information on GeoIP can be found [here.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.geoip.php)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers (GeoIP), you may try to analyze the `Accept-Language` header field and serve the content to users that accept finnish language.

You can modify the following function to parse `Accept-Language` header in PHP:

- [How to select content type from HTTP Accept header in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049401/how-to-select-content-type-from-http-accept-header-in-php/1087498#1087498)

Answer (score 1):

As yet another alternative, you can download one of the SQL databases here and use it to resolve an IP address to a location:

http://www.ipinfodb.com/ip_database.php

Also, [they offer an API](http://www.ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php) that does the same thing, but this may not be optimal if you're getting a lot of traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few bets you can try:

- convert the IP to a geographic location (PEAR: Net_GeoIP)
- check the requested language that is used in the browser, and use that. Problem is, a lot of people just have 'english' setup, so this won't always work.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pointer to **MaxMind GeoIP Country Database**.  http://www.maxmind.com/app/country.  It's about $50.00 and comes with a PHP library for accessing the information.