# 404 error on PHP local machine when trying to load external css file, but all Ok online

Tags: php, css

I can get the content of the CSS file when it´s running on my GoDaddy Windows shared hosting account. The CSS file is in the same directory of the index.php file:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all.css" media="screen" />
</head>
```

**But the things go wrong** when I try to run the same PHP and call the same CSS file in my local development machine. The Opera browser shows me the 404 error. No File Found. If I click the css link in Firefox, displays a browser empty window.

I don´t have problems when using several php resources on my local machine, MySql connections and queries too.

I am using a PHP manual installation and setup on Windows 7 and IIS as Web Server.

Looking for a fix I´ve checked in my local host the $_SERVER array, getting the next values:

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
The Document_Root is: C:\inetpub\wwwroot

The Script_FileName is: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sisco\index.php

The PHP_Self is: /sisco/index.php

The Path_Translated is: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sisco\index.php

The Original_Path Info is: /sisco/index.php

The Appl_Physical_Path is: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\

The HTTP_ACCEPT is: text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, image/webp, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Where **sisco** it´s the application directory, **index.php** and **all.css** are in that folder.

Why the CSS file does **NOT LOAD** in my local machine, while all goes Ok on GoDaddy Windows Shared Hosting servers?

Can anyone help me, Please? ***Thanks in advance...***

Comment: And you're sure that the files on the server and locally are *exactly* the same? I mean no typos, no missing files etc?

Comment: What's the local URL in the browser and where (from C:) is the all.css file?

Comment: Try to add `text/css` in your `HTTP_ACCEPT` (Thanks for informing me Popnoodles)

Comment: Hi @Popnoodles ,  these are the url´s:
http://localhost/sisco/index.php    and    C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sisco
Thanks for your time! Please tell me where I wrong...

Comment: @Stefan , I´m really newbie. Adding text/css to HTTP_ACCEPT is it something about php.ini file? In that case, how can I add that MIME Type? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Guerrero See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049401/how-to-select-content-type-from-http-accept-header-in-php for a nice explanation. P.S. What do you have installed on your local machine?

Comment: @Stefan , my local machine uses Windows 7 Home Premium as O.S., PHP manual installation and Internet Information Services as Web Server. As I can understand, the link you suggest me it´s about a more complex situation, I suppose.
Please, let me know if it is possible to add **text/css** under Windows and IIS Server.
I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix in the IIS options in the Windows installation features.
I've checked the boxes that enable the CSS read and processing capability.
   
I could access clicking the Start button>>Control Panel>> Programs>> Windows Features, and I have enabled HTTP features in IIS.
  
I guess that situation was generated because I have been using a **PHP over IIS manual installation and configuration**, so I have omitted some basic services.

***Thanks to all who supported me!***