# How can I return only what's inside my <pre> tag if someone makes a cURL or wget request to my link?

Tags: javascript, php, curl, wget, pre

I have a simple "hello world" python script here

> print("Hello World")

I uploaded it to my site (similar to Pastebin or GitHub gist)

> https://www.bunlongheng.com/raw/YWFjOGMxYTktM2Y5Mi00ZDdlLWI1NWQtOTg0Y2EwYjVlMDM5

When I shared the link, I can see the icon, and the title field as the actual text, it's nice. Tested in iPhone below

[image]

When I curl the link, I got `<title>` & `<link>` tags come with it like this:

```
<title>print(&quot;Hello World&quot;)</title><link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://i.imgur.com/yRk5mqb.png" /><pre>print(&quot;Hello World&quot;)</pre>
```

Which of course will break if I remotely executed my codes like this

```
curl https://www.bunlongheng.com/raw/YWFjOGMxYTktM2Y5Mi00ZDdlLWI1NWQtOTg0Y2EwYjVlMDM5 | python




  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   153    0   153    0     0    354      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   353
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    <title>print(&quot;Hello World&quot;)</title><link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://i.imgur.com/yRk5mqb.png" /><pre>print(&quot;Hello World&quot;)</pre>
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I return only what's inside my `<pre>` tag if someone makes a `cURL` or `wget` to my link?

Comment: Assuming it's not being spoofed, you can check the user-agent and see if it's cURL or wget.  Then you can modify the output accordingly.

Comment: I guess I can and should do that. Basically, no one will ever use my site but me, and online bots. Thanks for your suggestion;

Answer (score 4):

You could attempt to sniff [the `User-Agent` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) but it isn't a good way to determine what type of content to provide to a client.

A better approach (utilizing the features built into HTTP that are designed for handling different representations of the same content) might be to use the `Accept` header.

---

In **Python**, you could use the [`accept-types` module](https://pypi.org/project/accept-types/) for this.

```
return_type = get_best_match(request.META.get('HTTP_ACCEPT'), ['text/html', 'application/python'])

if return_type == 'application/python':
        return render_python()
else: 
        return render_html()
```

---

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049401/how-to-select-content-type-from-http-accept-header-in-php/1087498) for handling it in **PHP**.

---

Then the client could ask for the Python code if they wanted it:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/python" http://example.com/foo | python
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I think it's amazing.

Answer (score 1):

similar to Quentin, i would check if the Accept-header contains the string "html", and serve the html if it does. but if it does not explicitly mention html, serve the python directly. because all web-browsers say some version of `Accept: ...html...` (like Chrome says `Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9` )

while wget/curl/libcurl just says `Accept: */*`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how do we do that in PHP ?

Comment: @code8888 ```$wantsHTML = (false !== stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'] ?? "", 'html'));``` then ```if($wantsHTML){serve html} else {serve python}```

Comment: I'd recommend using a library which parses the Accept header properly. Substring matching like this is a naive approach. You could get false positives (e.g. serving html when the client only accepts xhtml) and you're failing to account for the quality parameters.

Comment: @Quentin you're technically right, but pretty much all websites get this wrong anyway. for example stackoverflow.com will serve HTML even though you say you only accept XHTML: ```curl -H 'Accept: application/xhtml+xml' 'https://stackoverflow.com'``` - do you want to send a bugreport?

Comment: @hanshenrik — As far as I know, Stackoverflow doesn't do any content-type negotiation at all so that isn't a bug. If you're going to use a feature, then you might as well get a prewritten, robust library that implements it properly and not reinvent the wheel badly.

Answer (score 0):

## For PHP

I ended up do this

> $userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
> if (stripos($userAgent, 'curl') !== false || stripos($userAgent, 'wget') !== false ){
> return $paste->raw;
> }

```
public function raw($uuid)
{
    $paste  = Paste::where('uuid', base64_decode($uuid))->first();

    $userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
    if (stripos($userAgent, 'curl') !== false || stripos($userAgent, 'wget') !== false ){
        return $paste->raw;
    }


    if($paste->type == 'json'){
        return response()->json($paste->data);
    } else {
        $result = htmlentities($paste->raw);
        return '<title>'.$result.'</title><link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://i.imgur.com/WWWynu9.png" /><pre>'.$result.'</pre>';           
    }
    
}
```

Now can I remotely execute `bash` or `python` from `cURL` without an extra HTML tag. The best part is that I don't have to compromise the icon and title for the browser & mobile browser.